# return a list with the results of the execution of a for loop

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I've just started to learn racket and I need to loop a list with an index.

Now, I'm using [for](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29):

```
#lang racket
(for ([index (in-range 0 (length list1))])
  (if (number? (list-ref list1 index))
      (function-numeric list1 index list2)
      (function-no-numeric list1 index list3)))
```

`function-numeric` and `function-no-numeric` return a list, and I need to create a list with those lists return by those functions. But I don't know how to do it.

Maybe with [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) could be easier, but I don't it.

How can I return a list of lists with my for loop?

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to program in an unfamiliar language and bend it into familiar shape. Legacy code, platform specifics, etc. But you imply you want to *learn* racket. You can't do that by trying to turn it into a C derivative. You can program in it that way if you insist, and sometimes its necessary for performance reasons, but you won't *learn* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, using indexes is the worst possible way to traverse a list and should be avoided: each `list-ref` operation is `O(n)`, because to reach element `i` you have to traverse all `i-1` elements before it, making the whole traversal a whopping `O(n^2)` operation. If you absolutely need them, then generate a separate list with the indexes.

For collecting the returned data in a list, we can make use of [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) to accumulate the result of each iteration, and we can even traverse in parallel more than one sequence of elements. Let's put all together:

```
(for/list ([element list1]
           [index (in-range (length list1))])
  (if (number? element)
      (function-numeric list1 index list2)
      (function-no-numeric list1 index list3)))
```

I just hope you're not using `list-ref` *again* inside `function-numeric` and `function-no-numeric`. Maybe there's a better way to structure your algorithm, to avoid indexes altogether - lists should not be used in the same way we use arrays! If your algorithm can't be modified to avoid indexes, then consider using a [`vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) instead, which is optimized for fast item retrieval using indexes.

Comment: I tried what you suggested me: "generate a separate list with the indexes", and I used with map, but map traverse the first list, and then the second.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. How did you call it? if you go like this: `(map (lambda (e1 e2) do-something) lst1 lst2)` it'll traverse both lists simultaneously.

Comment: This is what I did: `(define lst1 '(1 2 3 4))`, and `(map (lambda (e1 e2) (display e1)) lst1 (range 0 (length lst1)))`. And I get: `1234'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)`. Maybe I haven't understood what has happened.

Comment: That's not how `map` works, the `lambda` you use must _return_ something. `display` just prints a value in the console, and returns `#<void>`. Replace the `display` call with this: `(list e1 e2)` and you'll see that it works correctly.

Comment: So, I can use `map` instead of `for/list`, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, and that's more portable than using `for/list`, which only works in Racket.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just started to learn Racket, I really recommend against `for` and `for/list`. You should understand the basic first: what is a list.

A list (also known as linked list) is either:

- `empty`; or
- a `cons` of an element with another list

For example,

- `empty` is an empty list.
- `(cons 9 empty)` is a list with one element: `9`.
- `(cons 3 (cons 9 empty))` is a list with two elements: `3` and `9`.

Given a list, here are primitive operations (besides `cons`) that you can do.

- `(empty? lst)`: check whether or not `lst` is `empty`. For example, `(empty? empty)` evaluates to `#t` but `(empty? (cons 1 empty))` evaluates to `#f`.
- `(first lst)`: returns the first element of `lst` if `lst` is a `cons`. Error if `lst` is an `empty`. For example, `(first (cons 2 (cons 1 empty)))` evaluates to `2` but `(first empty)` results in an error.
- `(rest lst)`: returns the rest of `lst` if `lst` is a `cons`. Error if `lst` is an `empty`. For example, `(rest (cons 2 (cons 1 empty)))` evaluates to `(cons 1 empty)` but `(first empty)` results in an error.

With a combination of `first` and `rest`, you can access any element. If you have a list `(cons 5 (cons 4 (cons 3 (cons 2 empty))))` and you want to access the second element (which should be `4`), you would compute:

- `(rest lst)` which will give you `(cons 4 (cons 3 (cons 2 empty)))`
- `(first (rest lst))` which will give you `4`.

`list` is simply an abbreviation to construct a list easily

- `(list)` is an abbreviation for `empty`.
- `(list 9)` is an abbreviation for `(cons 9 empty)`
- `(list 1 2 3)` is an abbreviation for `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))`.

Other list operations are implemented using only the above primitive operations. For instance, `list-ref` is implemented as follows:

```
(define (my-list-ref xs i)
  (cond
    ;; a list is either empty
    [(empty? xs) (error 'out-of-bound)]
    ;; or a cons, where it's safe to use first and rest
    [(= i 0) (first xs)]
    [else (my-list-ref (rest xs) (- i 1))]))

;; (my-list-ref (list) 0) => out-of-bound error
;; (my-list-ref (list 4 5 6) 0) => 4
;; (my-list-ref (list 4 5 6) 1) => 5
;; (my-list-ref (list 4 5 6) 2) => 6
```

As Óscar López mentioned, although list looks similar to array, the way to think about them is very different. Using `list-ref` takes `O(i)` which is fine if you want to get the i-th element once, but it is not the right way to access all elements (or even a lot of elements). Instead, simply access all of them in one pass. For example, if I have a list `(list 2 3 4)` and I want to obtain another list with `10` added to each element of the original list, I would write:

```
(define (add10-all xs)
  (cond
    ;; a list is either empty, where (add10-all empty) should return empty
    [(empty? xs) empty]
    ;; or a cons, where we want to to add 10 to the first element, 
    ;; recur on the rest, and create a resulting cons
    [else (cons (+ 10 (first xs)) (add10-all (rest xs)))]))

;; (add10-all (list)) => (list)
;; (add10-all (list 2 3 4)) => (list 12 13 14)
```

In your case, you probably want:

```
;; assume function-numeric consumes an element from list1 and the whole list2
;; assume function-no-numeric consumes an element from list1 and the whole list3

(define (foo list1 list2 list3)
  (cond
    [(empty? list1) empty]
    [else
     (define e (first list1))
     (define out (if (number? e)
                     (function-numeric e list2)
                     (function-no-numeric e list3)))
     (cons out (foo (rest list1) list2 list3))]))

(foo list1 list2 list3)
```

or

```
;; assume function-numeric consumes an element from list1 and the corresponding element in list2
;; assume function-no-numeric consumes an element from list1 and the corresponding element in list3

(define (foo list1 list2 list3)
  (cond
    [(empty? list1) empty]
    [else
     (define e (first list1))
     (define out (if (number? e)
                     (function-numeric e (first list2))
                     (function-no-numeric e (first list3))))
     (cons out (foo (rest list1) (rest list2) (rest list3)))]))

(foo list1 list2 list3)
```

It could be that you want to do something else, but the structure should be similar to the above two code. For instance, if you happen to really need an index to compute `function-numeric` and `function-no-numeric`, you would write:

```
;; assume function-numeric consumes (1) an element from list1 (2) the corresponding element in list2 (3) an index
;; assume function-no-numeric consumes (1) an element from list1 (2) the corresponding element in list3 (3) an index

(define (foo list1 list2 list3 i)
  (cond
    [(empty? list1) empty]
    [else
     (define e (first list1))
     (define out (if (number? e)
                     (function-numeric e (first list2) i)
                     (function-no-numeric e (first list3) i)))
     (cons out (foo (rest list1) (rest list2) (rest list3) (+ i 1)))]))

(foo list1 list2 list3 0)
```

Comment: I did not know about `first` and `rest` I've always used `car` and `cdr`. Plus I always use `null?` instead of `empty` or just check the list against `'()`.